# Getting all integer solution to undertermined linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, diophantine-equations

I have undertermined linear system with small number (< 30) variables. The possible solution for variables is integer from 0 to 3. How effeciently can I find **all solutions**? I tried bruteforcing, but that was slow.

Is it possible with some mathematical software (Gurobi, Cplex)?

Comment: Generating functions will do it easily.

Comment: Did you want to find the number of solutions, or print all of these partitions?

Comment: print all solutions

Comment: How is it possible with generating functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am ignorant of integer programming, so this answer could be naïve.

Did you exploit the linear equations when brute forcing ?

I mean, assuming $M$ equations in $N$ unknowns, where $M<N$, you can write your system of equations like

$$[A|A']\left[\frac X{X'}\right]=\left[B\right]$$ where $A$ is square $m\times m$, and solve partially as
$$X=A^{-1}B-A^{-1}A'X'.$$

Then you can brute force on the independent unknowns ($X'$) and check the dependent ones, which will take $4^{N-M}$ SAXPY  operations instead of $4^N$, a significant saving if $M$ is close to $N$.

In theory all computations should be made exactly using fractional arithmetic, but floating-point accuracy should be enough for a first screening of the solutions.