# Getting all positive integer solution (All possible states of a chemical system) to undertermined linear system (Conservation law from stoichiometry)

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

Let a chemical system be defined as 
$${A<=>B<=>C}$$

Then the stoichiometry is given as
$$S=\begin{bmatrix}
-1& 1&  0&  0\\
1& -1& -1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 &-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Then the conservation law can be found as (MATLAB) $$C=rref(null(S′,′r′)′)′$$
Then
$$C=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
For a closed chemical system, if the initial state, $\vec{X}(0)$ ($\vec X(t)$= number of molecules A, B, C at time t), is given, then for all time, states will satisfy the conservation. That means
$$C^T\vec{X}(t)=C^T\vec{X}(0)\hspace{1cm} \forall t$$

In the case of chemical system explained here, for an initial state $\vec X(0)=\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&0\end{bmatrix}^T$,
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\vec{X}(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=3$$

Then the question is **how can I identify all possible $\vec X(t)$ such that $x_i\in \mathbb Z_+ \ge 0$**

What I need is a general strategy that can find all columns of $\{X\}$ given below.

$$\{X\}=\begin{bmatrix}
     0  &  1&     2&     3&     0  &   0    & 0   &  1  &   1   &  2\\
     0   &  0&     0&     0&     1  &   2   &  3  &   1 &    2  &   1\\
     3    & 2 &    1 &    0 &    2   &  1   &  0  &   1  &   0  &   0
\end{bmatrix}$$

As you can see
$$C^T\{X\}=\begin{bmatrix}3&3&3&3&3&3&3&3&3&3\end{bmatrix}$$

There is no other positive integer combination is possible other than these columns. So basically I need to solve an equation

$$Ax=b\hspace{1cm} A\in \mathbb Z_+^{d\times n}\hspace{1cm} x\in \mathbb Z_+^{1\times n}\ge 0 \hspace{1cm} b\in \mathbb Z_+^{1\times d} \ge 0\hspace{1cm} d< n$$

A similar question: [Getting all integer solution to undertermined linear system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030644/getting-all-integer-solution-to-undertermined-linear-system)

Comment: In general integer programming is hard, but Integer solutions to linear equation systems are on *lattices* which I've heard have some nice theory and seems to have some software including the LattE Tobias describes below.

Answer (score 1):

Finding all the solutions to a given system of $\mathbb{Z}$-linear equations is a hard mathematical problem. In your application, is $A$ always $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$? If so, then for an initial state $X\in\mathbb{Z}_+^3$, the solutions to your system are precisely the [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) of $X_1+X_2+X_3\in\mathbb{N}$ into $3$ parts.

For general matrixes $A$ and right-hand sides $b$, you can use the software [LattE](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/) which counts the number of solutions.

Comment: In general, A is not the particular vector explained above. It can be any non-negative matrix. Is there any Matlab implementation of the theory in LattE?

Comment: @MidhunKathanaruparambil: As far as I know, there is no interface to Matlab.